# How do I create a method, and make a constructer that calls the method

Tags: c#

All in the Title.

Also please give an answer in less than a week.

I need someone to really help me with this, I'm using an online course and it says I have to Write the NumberBoard method, then write a NumberBoard constructer and call the method.

Here's the link to the .zip file that has the PDF telling me what to do, and the project that they give you:

https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/gameprogramming%2Frequired_assessment_materials%2FRequiredProjectMaterials.zip

(Copy and paste if link not clickable)

To get to the project, open the code folder and click the "GameProject" thing

Comment: Hi welcome to SO, be specific and post the relevant code instead of giving the entire project to other.

Comment: You don't need to call a constructor method - it will execute when you instantiate the object. I suggest you read the course material in a bit more detail before asking exercise related questions...

Comment: *"Also please give an answer in less than a week"* - so is it you or us that's doing this online course?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will work

```
    public class SomeClass
    {
        public SomeClass() //constructor
        {
            SomeMethod(); //Calling the method in constructor
        }
        public void SomeMethod() // Method
        {
            //Method implementation
        }
    }
```